# Add custom headers to all resources in all modules

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular JS site, I have many modules & many resources (From where I consume Rest API)

I want to add a custom header to all outgoing requests in each & every module.

For eg : Here are 2 modules : common & ABC

```
//---File 1 common.js
angular.module("common",[])
.config(['$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) 
    {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = 
    'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJOYW1lIjoiQWJkdWwiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjUwMzkwMzgsImV4cCI6MTQ2NTEyNTQzOH0.6BMBuEl2dbL736qUqNYXG29UBn_HRyCyWEmMXSG3euE';
    }
])
.service("commonApi",['$resource',
    function($resource)
    {
        this.getBankList = function()       
        {
            return $resource('api/emi/banklist:quoteId', {  },{}).query(); 
        }
    }]);


//---File 2 abc.js

angular.module("abc",[])
.config(['$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) 
    {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = 
    'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJOYW1lIjoiQWJkdWwiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjUwMzkwMzgsImV4cCI6MTQ2NTEyNTQzOH0.6BMBuEl2dbL736qUqNYXG29UBn_HRyCyWEmMXSG3euE';
    }
])
.factory('emiModel', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/emi/QuoteList:quoteId', {  }, {
        update: {   method: 'PUT'   }
        });
    }])
```

In the above code, I had to add .config to each module & add the header there.

It is quite time consuming to add it in each module & **violates DRY principle.**

Is there any simple way by which I can add this configuration to all modules in my app without repeating the code ?

**For Carity :** I used factory & service just to show that i might be using any thing but I still want the header to be passed.

Comment: Have you seen about '$http interceptor' ?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant even using interceptor I will have to repeat it or add a dependency in all modules

Comment: `add a dependency in all modules` yes it's normal. If you just have to register, it doesn't violates DRY: you will have to register it.*

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant It doesn't make sense to add a dependency & add an extra line of interceptor.push in each module. what if my project has 8-10 people working on it & around 100+ modules & someone fails to add it ? I want to reduce the chances of mistakes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above code, I had to add .config to each module & add the
>   header there.
>
> It is quite time consuming to add it in each module & violates DRY
>   principle.

This isn't true. Once the module is loaded, Angular doesn't make a difference between them.

`config` block affects each and every module in the app that has `common` module loaded. I.e. all of `$http` calls will be affected with `config` in this setup:

```
angular.module("app",["abc", "common"])...
angular.module("abc",[])...
```

Though it is recommended to load `common` module in each submodule that depends on `config`, too. So they don't break in the case when they are loaded apart from `app` (e.g. in specs).

Comment: You are Right . it does execute but my problem turned out to be something else, The token i hardcoded in eg actually comes from local storage & what happens is, it does not get re-evaluated. so after logging in the token is never taken by the provider.

Comment: localStorage is synchronous and can be loaded in `config`. If it isn't possible for some reasons, use interceptors, as the comment above suggests. Interceptors can be defined in `config` and they are evaluated on each request.